# Python websockets connecting through the internet using IPV6

Tags: python, websocket, ipv6

I want to send messages between two PCs accessing the internet through different networks. I have already created a firewall rule for the port in the server PC. The code works when both of them are using the same WiFi but not when using different connections.

Server (PC #1)

```
import asyncio
import websockets

import socket

async def hello(websocket):
    name = await websocket.recv()
    print(f"<<< {name}")

    greeting = f"Hello {name}!"

    await websocket.send(greeting)
    print(f">>> {greeting}")

async def main():
    async with websockets.serve(hello, "", port=8765):
        await asyncio.Future()  # run forever

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Client (PC #2)

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import socket
        
async def hello():

    uri = "ws://[2a02:8388:8bc7:4d00:1921:8126:966d:8d32]:8765"
    #not my real IP

    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        name = input("What's your name? ")

        await websocket.send(name)
        print(f">>> {name}")

        greeting = await websocket.recv()
        print(f"<<< {greeting}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(hello())
```

Comment: normal this seems to be a routing problem. You need to make sure that there is at least one IP-ROUTE between the two...do they share the same router? do you have a static route?

Comment: i'm trying to connect over the internet, where the 2 computers don't share a router.

Comment: are there two IPV6 public IPs? if not this is not possible (also take into account that if your two devices are each behind routers you need to conf a port forwarding)